# Receiver has no segue with identifier"***"

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I encounter this problem for the first time. I checked similar problems on stack overflow, but none of the solutions can solve my issue so I have this posting.

Up to the present, I have two view `controllers`(let's say A and B) and I am trying to connect them with a segue with name "toB". When I run the program, Xcode told me `Receiver(B) has no segue with identifier "toB"`.

I am pretty sure that the spellings of the `identifier`in the `storyboard` and in the code are exactly the same. And the line of the segue has connected the `A view controller` and `B view controller`.

But the `storyboard` IDs of the two view `controllers` are different. Is it the problem??

Hope someone could help me out. Thanks in advance!

---

**SOLUTION**

Thanks for @Amit Shelgaonkar's hint! In my case, moving the `performSegueWithIdentifier` to `viewDidAppear` still doesn't work, but moving it to `applicationWillEnterForeground` solves the problem!

I still don't know why it doesn't work in my case, because when I tried to develop a testing app and put the `performSegueWithIdentifier` in `viewDidAppear`, it works perfectly.

Comment: Can you post some code, e.g. where you call `performSegueWithIdentifier:`?

Comment: Add your storyboard picture to see how two view controllers are connected.

Comment: @KathiravanG I don't have enough reputation to post images...  Here is the link, sorry to take you away from stack overflow![link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzuHHdjzRAbdVGxjSjAzZHRjTDA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Glorfindel I call the `performSegueWithIdentifier` in `viewDidLoad` of the first view controller in the stortyboard. The relevant code is very simple, just `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toB" sender:self];`

Comment: @JennyCheung In the attached image the segue you mentioned in blue colour has different name (toQSG). Whether you checked?

Comment: @KathiravanG yes, I have checked. Actually I said A and B just for simplification. sorry for the confusion! You may assume QSG==B

Comment: @JennyCheung can you post the exact message what Xcode giving while you running

Comment: @KathiravanG Sorry again for the confusion!!! I will pay attention to the way I describe my question next time!!!  and the message screen capture is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzuHHdjzRAbdbEFyZG1CbGprd28/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @JennyCheung its look like your given name in storyboard and code not matches some times little spaces also give issue. Try to delete the old name and give the new segue name and copy this name don't copy the spaces and try

Comment: Please make a screenshot of the `UIStoryboard` and also insert the code where you perform the segue, or the `prepareForSegue:` if you do additional stuff inside, otherwise nobody will be able to help you with your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you call `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` in the `viewDidLoad`. You can not dismiss a `UIViewController` that isn't presented yet. `viewDidLoad` has purely memory management functions, you can use it as (part of a) constructor. What may work, is to start a `segue` in `viewDidAppear`, however I would suggest to start with the view you want at the first time.

Comment: @ Jenny Cheung if you think it is useful please accept my answer.

Comment: I tried to move the `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender ` to `viewDidAppear `, but still not working. Could you please give me more help?

Answer (score 1):

What to check:
1. Segue between A and B, name of segue.
2. Code should look like this: `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toB" sender:self];`
3. Check that your B view has custom class.
**4. Try cleaning project and run again.**

Comment: What is your type of segue?

Comment: I call the `performSegueWithIdentifier` in the `viewDidLoad` of the first view controller in the storyboard, is it a problem?

Comment: the segue is of type modal

Comment: Why would you do that? You should call performSegueWithIdentifier in A.

Comment: yes, A is the first view controller in the storyboard

Comment: How you jump from A to B? On button or what?

Comment: by satisfying a condition

Comment: and I have checked that the condition is satisfied

Comment: B view controller handles a Quick start guide, and A is the first controller of the app. at the beginning of the app, I would like it to check whether the user uses the app for the first time or not, by checking the version number. If the version number is nil, which means the users uses it for the first time, I would like to show the quick start guide first.

Comment: Try to clean your project.

Comment: This is example of condition that I used to perform segue:
if (self.orderArray.count == 0) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toSelectionSegue" sender:self];  
    }

Answer (score 0):

Bit old but hope this helps as I was having the same issue. Having run through all the suggestions here, the issue turned out to be on my receiving view, in the class declaration for that view I had set it as ViewController and not a UIViewController.

e.g. I had this originally and is wrong

```
class viewB: ViewController{
```

and this is right

```
class viewB: UIViewController{
```